# PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Votes"

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core

I am using EF Core 6.0.5. I am getting error when I am trying to insert something to database. Error like below :
`PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Votes"`

I have two classes

User Class :

```
    public class User:IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Vote Class

```
    public class Vote
    {
        public int VoteId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string TaskId { get; set; }
        public int VotePoint { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext

```
    public class ScrumDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, VoteRole, string> //
    {
        public ScrumDbContext(DbContextOptions<ScrumDbContext> options) : base(options) {}
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    }
```

And last one, function I got an error.

```
        public int AddVote(Vote vote)
        {
            _context.Votes.Add(vote);
            var result = _context.SaveChanges(); //I am getting error in this line.
            if (result == 1)
                return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try [Key] for the field of Vote.VoteId? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations. Dont forget to remove old records in table

Comment: No need to get [Key] attribute. It's already automatic. An example from Migration:           `migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "VoteId",
                table: "Votes",
                type: "integer",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn);

            migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
                name: "PK_Votes",
                table: "Votes",
                column: "VoteId");`

Comment: migration is another type of beast. it seems you need to configure the mappings of entities.

Comment: I am getting exception directly, it means as you said in first time. won't duplicate.

Comment: You can put ```Database.Log = x => Debug.WriteLine(x);``` to your dbcontext constructor to see the sql commands. somehow same id-value goes to db